# IrDA adapter - how to enable speeds less than 9600

Tags: drivers, serial-port, infrared, sigmatel, irda

I need to use infrared usb adapter tekram IR-410W under win8.
unfortunately it doesnt create virtual com ports. 
another trouble is IrCOMM driver doesnt work under win7/8

i need to communicate to slow speed 300bps device, however sigmatel driver (irda is shown as sigmatel) doesn't let me select speeds less than 9600 :(

as i understood virtual com port shall be created automatically when there is irda connection with device (very strange to me), however i can't select proper speed.

any ideas are welcome. thank you.

p.s. as for com port drivers - i tried IrCOMM driver, tried drivers from Ftdichip.com - no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try Windows Update if it can automatically find drivers. Then it should create the port and in Device Manager you should see it and select the speed. But as far as I know 9600 is the lowest speed for a COM port. This means up to 9600, so if the device cannot keep up the data exchange will be at lower speed, but up to 9600. It doesn't mean that the data transfer will always be at 9600.